# Why do Google Play Services need two certificates for downloadable fonts?

Tags: android, android-downloadable-fonts

I'm using Support Library for downloadable fonts. I followed the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html#adding-certificates), which says:

> When a font provider is not preinstalled or if you are using the support library, you must declare the certificates the font provider is signed with. The system uses the certificates to verify the font provider's identity.

So it's obvious that in order to use Google Font provider, I need to add the certificates for Google Play Services.

```
<resources>
  <array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
    <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev</item>
    <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod</item>
  </array>
  <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev">
    <item>
        [HASH]
    </item>
  </string-array>
  <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod">
    <item>
        [HASH]
    </item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

What I can't find anywhere is, *why* are there two certificates: `dev` and `prod`? And when does each get used?

Comment: Did you find any new information on that?

Answer (score 0):

One is optimized for production, the general is this, when you develop locally, the dev version is used, however the key difference is application APK signing. When your application is officially signed and ready for deployment the prod font set is triggered.

Comment: Reduces the APK size

Comment: How do Play Services know if they are used in the development version or production one? And what if I have more variants, not just dev and prod?

Comment: Its easy actually, remember they are many build variants, prod and dev in gradle, when ever a application is ever SIGNED, the production release code is triggered. The google play reads all files, and because its a production deployment it selects the prod certificate

Comment: @Remario Do you mean we still need to provide both certificates for all build variants, but the library will runtime choose which certificate to use?

Comment: What does this "optimize" exactly? What's the benefit?